# How to add the additional email in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have PowerShell script to send email. In that script mail is delivered only the last email id (test2@test.com). But the mail is not delivered to 1st email id (test1@gmail.com).

```
##Send email functionality from below line, use it if you want   
$smtpServer = ""
$smtpFrom = "test@test.com"
$smtpTo = 'test1@test.com','test2@test.com'
$messageSubject = "Servers Health report"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.Body = "<head><pre>$style</pre></head>"
$message.Body += Get-Content C:\scripts\test.htm
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to correctly handle passing multiple recipients. Otherwise the last will always overwrite the first.

```
$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Message.From = $SmtpFrom

foreach ($_ in $SmtpTo) {
    $Message.To.Add($_)
}
```